# Read Write option of registers

Tags: embedded, hardware

I found this -> **R/C** notation in one Atmel chip specification, in section registers:

[image]

I assume that it stands for **Read Clear** register, as it is sometimes in Interrupt Status Registers. But something bothers me. Usually the notation of those registers is **RC**. <- Note without the forth-slash between the letters. Into the same document the notation of R/W means that the register can be read or written, but not at the same time, or with the same command/instruction. So the forth-slash symbol must represent mutually exclusive operation, NOT the one inevitably follows the other.

So what R/C means:

- when read the register is automatically cleared?
- the register can be read or cleared? - But then how is it cleared?

Comment: There should be a table in the same doc, or other similar docs that have a legend.  That or experiment if you can.  Or contact Atmel.

Comment: it could mean clear on read sure but I would do further research to confirm that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're talking about [this datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-46003-SE-M90E32AS-Datasheet.pdf), you posted information from the register list.  If you had looked in the **Comment** column of that list, it says "*Refer to Table-11*".  Going to Table 11, it says "*Resolution is 0.01CF. Cleared after read.*" Table 12 similarly says that they are Cleared after read.